$U$ subspace $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dimension $n-1$ implying $U$ is an $n-1$-dimensional hyperplane
I was tutoring and helping with the following linear algebra problem:

$U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\dim U = n -1$. Show that there are reals $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ such that if $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in U$ then $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \ldots + a_n x_n = 0$.

I have a solution that I think is a wee sloppy, so I wanted to know if a more lucid argument could be made. Note that the material thus far has not covered orthogonal complements or the like, rather one must rely merely on the fundamental theory of linear spaces and bases.
Here is how I approached it:
We can write $U = \text{span} \{ v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{n-1} \}$, where $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$ is a basis of $U$. Take any $x \in U$. Then there exist unique $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_{n-1}$ such that
$$
x = \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 + \ldots + \lambda_{n-1} v_{n-1}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
|  & | & \cdots & |\\
v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_{n-1} \\ 
|  & | & \cdots & |
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\x_2 \\ \vdots \\x_{n-1} \\x_n \end{pmatrix}
$$
The coefficient matrix has $n$ rows and $n-1$ columns. Since a unique solution must exist, upon row reducing the matrix, we will find leading ones in every column. But the last row will become a row with all zeros as entries, and in the right-hand side the row reduction processs will leave a linear combination of all the $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, which must be zero in order to avoid an absurdity.
Hence that shows there are $a_i$ such that $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \ldots + a_n x_n = 0$. But in my case I have not explicitly stated all the $a_i$ in terms of the basis vectors $v_i$, since it would be too cumbersome.
Could this be argued differently (without orthogonal complements)? Thanks.

This is not a correct solution at all: your $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ depend on $\mathbf{x}$, but the question asks for $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ that work for all $\mathbf{x}$.

@ArturoMagidin: Hm I see what you mean. But, if you take any other $y \in U$ and perform the exact same row reduction process, you will end up with the exact same linear combination in the last row, with the exact same coefficients $a_i$ depending on the basis vectors $v_i$, and not the chosen $y \in U$. So you get the same linear combination regardless of choice of element in $U$. Or am I mistaken?

"You will end up with the exact same linear combination in the last row". You need to prove that. Which would likely require you to express this formally with elementary matrices. Instead, use the orthogonal complement of $U$.

You don't really need orthogonality, Gauss, determinants or really anything.  You just need to know that the matrix appearing in the display has a left kernel vector.  (In vector space language, you need to extend the $v_i$ to a basis and then use the linear functional from the dual basis associated to the basis vector you added.)

Big hint: $$x\in U\iff\det(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},x)=0.$$
Note that $\Bbb R$ can be replaced by any field.

Very nice, we can expand the determinant along the $x$-column: $ 0 = (-1)^n M_{1,n} \cdot x_1 + (-1)^{n+1}  M_{2,n} \cdot x_2 + \cdots + (-1)^{2n -1} M_{n,n}  \cdot x_n $. Determinants have however not been introduced yet at the point of this problem though, but I really like this argument, thank you

Let $A$ be an $n\times(n-1)$ matrix that has $U$ as its column span.  Because it has more rows than columns, there is a non-zero vector $v\in F^n$ so that $v^t A = \mathbf{0}$.
Now, let $x\in U$ be given.  There is a $y\in F^{n-1}$ so that $x = Ay$.  So then we have $v^t x = v^t Ay = \mathbf{0}y = 0$.

I should remark that, unlike if you use determinants, this answer generalises to $U$ of higher codimenson.

Nice, this looks the intended approach I think. However, how do you have in mind justifying the claim, "Because it has more rows than columns, there is a non-zero vector $v \in F^n$ so that $v^t A = 0$"? I would say: The columns in $A$ are linearly independent so all columns have pivot elements, and consequently in $A^t$ all rows have pivot elements. Hence $A^t v = 0$ is solvable by a $v \neq 0$ in $F^n$, since there will be a free variable in the system $A^t v = 0$. Hence $v^t A = 0$, as promised. Would you argue differently (and perhaps more efficiently)? Thank you

@kapython The columns of $A^t$ are $n$ vectors in an $(n-1)$-dimensional space, so they must be an LD set. Put the coefficients of any non-trivial dependence into $v$ and you get $A^tv = \mathbf{0}$.  You are already using this language, so no need to faff around with RREF and pivots.

Excellent, looking at number of vectors and the dimension of the space they live in was much cleaner. Thank you

Louis has suggested a great solution. I will try to make it more explicit.
From the definition of dimension, $\dim U=n-1$ implies that any basis of $U$ contains $n-1$ vectors. We denote one of these sets as $\{u_1, u_2,..., u_{n-1}\}$. These $n-1$ vectors are linearly independent of one another, and the span of this set of vectors is $U$.
Now we define matrix $A$ whose columns are the basis vectors
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
| & | & ... & | \\
u_1 & u_2 & ... & u_{n-1} \\
| & | & ... & | \\
\end{bmatrix}
\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times (n-1)}
\end{equation}
Any $x\in U$ can be represented as $x=Ac$ where $c\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Now, we take the transpose of $x$
\begin{equation}
x^T=c^TA^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 & c_2 & ... & c_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
- & u_1^T & - \\
- & u_2^T & - \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
- & u_{n-1}^T & - \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Notice that $A^T$ is an $(n-1)\times n$ matrix.
Since all the rows are linearly independent (because we constructed $u_1,...,u_{n-1}$ as the basis of $U$), the homogeneous system $A^Ta=0$ is guaranteed to have infinitely many solutions. Any $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies this system would satisfy the following:
\begin{equation}
A^Ta = 0 \implies c^TA^Ta = 0 \implies x^Ta=0 \implies a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...a_nx_n=0
\end{equation}
Vector $a$ does not depend on the specific $c$ used to construct $x$. Instead, $a$ depends solely on the $n-1$ basis chosen to construct matrix $A$.
Note that the basis $\{u_1, u_2,..., u_{n-1}\}$ is chosen without loss of generality, so our proof shows that infinitely many $a$ would exist for any basis of $U$. We also know that any $x\in U$ is a linear combination of basis vectors from the definition of a basis. Thus, we showed that for any $x\in U$, we can always find $a$ (in fact infinitely many) such that $x^T a=0$.

As a further note, these $a$ spans the orthogonal complement of $U$. Intuitively, this would be the line normal to the hyperplane formed by $U$.

Why is this downvoted twice?
